# how can I run rails server daemon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, start-stop-daemon

I am new at rails world and need to run my rails test server in daemon mode..

I've noticed that there is a  a -d flag but its not working for me..

```
rails -s -d
```

shouldn't it be like this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

it's worth trying the following command

```
$ rails s -d
```

Comment: @JKABC 'rails s' is alternate shorthand for 'rails server.' They both do the same thing.

Answer (score 89):

It should be:

```
rails server --daemon

# to kill the server
kill `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`

# to tail development logs for debugging
tail -f log/development.log
```

Comment: Please use long option/command names, when giving an advice – novices will appreciate it.

Comment: rails s -d is not working for me is there any other update?

Comment: Is there anyway to re-attach if you need to debug the logs?

Comment: @jahrichie You can tail the log file `tail -f development.log` to debug the logs.

Comment: for me to tail logs: `tail -f log/development.log`