# Unable to start rails server with -d switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to start rails server as a daemon using the `-d` switch. I have installed thin server and working on Ubuntu. If it is started as a normal process, it works, but when using the `-d` switch, it complains of a server pid file `/tmp/pids/server.pid`

Even if I delete the file and try to start the server with `-d` switch, it won't start. Please help.

The error says:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activated daemons 1.1.9, but your Gemfile requires daemons 1.1.8. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/deploys/releases/20131001113746/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/deploys/releases/20131001113746/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/deploys/releases/20131001113746/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/deploys/releases/20131001113746/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/deploys/releases/20131001113746/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/deploys/releases/20131001113746/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in `for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:169:in `load_adapter'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:73:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/thin:23:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Make sure /tmp directory is accessible to rails server?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964002/how-can-i-run-rails-server-daemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the server using 'bundle exec' in the start like:

```
bundle exec rails s -d
```

Alternatively, your exception trace is stating a mismatch for the activated daemons gem. To fix this, set the version of daemons gem to be greater than (instead of equal to) 1.1.8 and try.